# Access to a Webpage on a virtualbox client from host, both Ubuntu, Neo4j Project

Tags: linux, ubuntu, neo4j, virtualbox

***Problem***

I tried to set up a VirtualBox Client with Ubuntu (Server Edition) running a neo4j database for web development.
It all seemed to work (eg. SSH and SFT connection work), until I wanted to access the web frontend of the former mentioned DB.

In detail, i want to open port 7474 on my client through my webbrowser on my host machine.

I already crawled the web for answers, but none where applicable or solved my problem.

***Setup***

My host system is an **Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 bit** machine, running the **VirtualBox GUI in Version 4.3.10**

The client VM is a fresh install of **Ubuntu 14.10 server 64 bit** including the SSH package.
I use the **Network-Bridge** connection to **eth0** of my host (see details below) with **promiscuous Mode: allow for all VMs and Host**.
The only other packages installed are **neo4j and its dependencies**.

I installed neo4j and, as far as I can tell, it's up and running. At least that's what `service neo4j-service status` said (`* neo4j is running`).

I don't have any apache or lighttp installed.

That's what `ifconfig` says on my **host** machine (sorry, it's in German)

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse d4:3d:7e:50:3b:2d  
          inet Adresse:192.168.0.45  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Maske:255.255.255.0
          inet6-Adresse: fe80::d63d:7eff:fe50:3b2d/64 Gültigkeitsbereich:Verbindung
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metrik:1
          RX-Pakete:71671 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
          TX-Pakete:53988 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
          Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1000 
          RX-Bytes:46107644 (46.1 MB)  TX-Bytes:10170816 (10.1 MB)

lo        Link encap:Lokale Schleife  
          inet Adresse:127.0.0.1  Maske:255.0.0.0
          inet6-Adresse: ::1/128 Gültigkeitsbereich:Maschine
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metrik:1
          RX-Pakete:1836 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
          TX-Pakete:1836 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
          Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:0 
          RX-Bytes:185486 (185.4 KB)  TX-Bytes:185486 (185.4 KB)
```

And on my **client**

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse 08:00:27:15:31:ca  
          inet Adresse:192.168.0.18  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Maske:255.255.255.0
          inet6-Adresse: fe80::a00:27ff:fe15:31ca/64 Gültigkeitsbereich:Verbindung
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metrik:1
          RX-Pakete:9690 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
          TX-Pakete:96 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
          Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1000 
          RX-Bytes:828688 (828.6 KB)  TX-Bytes:12046 (12.0 KB)

lo        Link encap:Lokale Schleife  
          inet Adresse:127.0.0.1  Maske:255.0.0.0
          inet6-Adresse: ::1/128 Gültigkeitsbereich:Maschine
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metrik:1
          RX-Pakete:999 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
          TX-Pakete:999 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
          Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:0 
          RX-Bytes:97214 (97.2 KB)  TX-Bytes:97214 (97.2 KB)
```

So I was trying to open `http://192.168.0.18:7474` in my browser (Firefox and Opera as well), but none of both could establish a connection.

I can ping to 8.8.8.8 (google) and to my host / client from either one, so the whole problem should be in the ports, I presume.

I also already tried to `sudo ufw disable`, but it didn't helped.
The clients `sudo iptables -L -n` says now

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

I would appreciate any help, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Neo4j just listens on the localhost interface for security reasons. You can open that up to the world by setting `org.neo4j.server.webserver.address=0.0.0.0` in your `$NEO4J_HOME/conf/neo4j-server.properties`.

Comment: Thank you very much, but i can't find that path... I tried `echo $NEO4J_HOME` but got an empty result, whereas `echo $PATH` delivers the expected result. I installed neo4j via apt-get, any idea how I could find the Path to the conf directory?

Comment: When installing via apt-get you should find this file under /etc/neo4j

Comment: Thank you so much, you were right.The absolute Path is `/etc/neo4j/neo4j-server.properties`

Answer (score 1):

I installed the `Neo4j 3.4.0 Community Edition` in a `Ubuntu 16.04` virtual box instance using the instructions provided in [here](https://datawookie.netlify.com/blog/2016/09/installing-neo4j-on-ubuntu-16.04/) and in order to open up the `Neo4j browser` to my `OSX Host` I needed to

1. Navigate to `/etc/neo4j`
2. vim `neo4j.conf` - the only file that is there
3. Find the property `dbms.connectors.default_listen_address=0.0.0.0` and uncomment it
4. Restart and test in your host (assuming your vm's network adapter settings are configured - in my case it is `Host-only Adapter`)

I could not find the `neo4j-server.properties` and also the property seem to be have different name than what is mentioned in [Stefan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28929920/1225551). Hopefully I did not turn on the wrong property.

Comment: Try looking in "<neo4j-home>/conf/neo4j.conf" https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/configuration/file-locations/